# How to print my http query results in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, http, get

I am trying to create an app that would allow a user to get GitHub repos based on their query (basically a mobile GitHub search for repos).

I have created with some kind people's from stack overflow help this code:

```
import UIKit

    func APIcall() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=CoreData&per_page=20") else {
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/vnd.github.v3+json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
    }
```

How do I print out the list of 20 repos I asked for in this code?

I add Github API documentation as a reference:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-repositories

Comment: You are doing creating the `URLRequest`, you need to perform it. Loook for `URLSession`. There are plenty of question about how do a HTTP request, did you look at them? They should use `URLSession`.

Comment: Yes I think I've done it, but didn't see anything to useful there. Will try to revisit. Thanks, @Larme

Comment: Or look for a tutorial, there should be plenty, now that you have your `URLRequest`.

Comment: Thanks, @Larme,

I continue my endeavours here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70612447/no-value-associated-with-key-codingkeys-while-trying-to-get-data-from-github-api

Thank you for pushing me in the right direction :)