# Passing a value form python file to the iOS app

Tags: python, ios, swift, xcode

I need to create and iOS app that is basically a mobile GitHub repository browser. A user passes their input and they get the search results for the repositories.

I have tried approaching it from the basic http point of view, but to na avail (check out this question):

[How to print my http query results in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70573291/how-to-print-my-http-query-results-in-xcode?fbclid=IwAR23iqZN2Ah-_YkHgprIDjm7iVL3sHjJNm44q9y2033bE3gEc6LwLNiJZuM)

And now with support from @HedgeHog I have found a piece of code which does exactly what the backend to my app should do; but is written in Python:

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4

print('Your GitHub repository search query:')
userInput = input()

results = requests.get('https://github.com/search?q=' + userInput + '&type=repositories'
                       + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
results.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(results.text, 'html.parser')

linkList = ['https://github.com/'+a['href'] for a in soup.select('.repo-list-item .f4 a[href]')]
```

As I have also learned, PythonKit doesn't support iOS apps.
Is there any way that I could put a *.py file in the Xcode project and that Xcode could run it as a function (pass an input from a Swift to the Python file, then receive an output to the Swift file)?

Comment: You are much better of learning about the swift classes URLSession, URLRequest etc and then using Codable to decode json than trying to pass data between python and swift.

Comment: Could you recommend any tutorials, @JoakimDanielson, please?

Comment: I am following this app's creation endeavours in another thread. Thanks for showing me the direction, @JoakimDanielson:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70612447/no-value-associated-with-key-codingkeys-while-trying-to-get-data-from-github-api