# No value associated with key CodingKeys while trying to get data from GitHub API in Xcode app

Tags: swift, http, github-api

So listening to @Larme and @JoakimDanielson (thanks a lot, guys!) I started doing some tasks on URLSessions to actually get the data I am looking for from GitHub API.

The endgame here is to create a mobile GitHub search app for repositories.

I have realised a code from this tutorial:
https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-make-http-requests-with-urlsession-in-swift-4dced0287d40

Using relevant GitHub API URL. My code looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class Repository: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let owner, name, full_name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case owner, name, full_name
    }

    init(id: Int, owner: String, name: String, fullName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.owner = owner
        self.name = name
        self.full_name = full_name
    }
}
```

(...)

```
        let session = URLSession.shared
                let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=CoreData&per_page=20")!
                let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                    // Check the response
                    print(response)
                    
                    // Check if an error occured
                    if error != nil {
                        // HERE you can manage the error
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                    
                    // Serialize the data into an object
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Repository.self, from: data! )
                            //try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                        print(json)
                    } catch {
                        print("Error during JSON serialization: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        print(String(describing:error))
                    }
                    
                })
                task.resume()
        
        
    }
    


}
```

The full error text is:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

I tried removing some values that had this error but the others still threw the same and I used the coding keys I could find in the GitHub docs:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-repositories

Please help!

Comment: Print the entire error: `print("Error during JSON serialization:", error)`. And where is the struct representing the root object with the keys`total_count`, `incomplete_results` and `items`?

Comment: Hint: `full_name` and `fullName` are two different things.

Comment: I have a problem with id and owner to start things off, the errors didn't even reach full_name, @matt

Comment: The whole error text printed, @vadian.
How to reference the root object in the struct? I am a total noob in creating http requests in Xcode.
Could you point me to further reading about this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need `CodingKeys` and the `init` method.
Second of all use structs, not classes.

If you want to decode the repositories you have to start with the root object, the repositories are in the array for key `items`

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let items : [Repository]
}

struct Repository: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name, fullName: String
    let owner : Owner
}

struct Owner : Decodable {
    let login : String
}
```

Another issue is that `owner` is also a Dictionary which becomes another struct.

To get rid of the CodingKeys add the `.convertFromSnakeCase` strategy which *translates* `full_name` into `fullName`.

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=CoreData&per_page=20")!
let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    // Check the response
    print(response)
    // Check if an error occured
    if let error = error {
        // HERE you can manage the error
        print(error)
        return
    }
    
    // Serialize the data into an object
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let json = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data! )
        print(json)
    } catch {
        print("Error during JSON serialization:", error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```