# Errors while trying to create a list based on JSON in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui

I need my JSON data to be translated to a list as an output for an app I am creating.

I have found this tutorial, which seems to be using some old elements like "BindableObject":

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ri1A032zfLo

As far as I've checked several times, I went word for word in the NetworkingManager file being described from 1:52 in the video (just changing the names and the URL). My code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

/*BindableObject was renamed to ObservableObject */

class NetworkingManager: ObservableObject{
    var didChange: PassthroughSubject <NetworkingManager, Never>
    
    var gitHubList = Root(items: []){
        didSet{
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=CoreData&per_page=20") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in guard let data = data else { return }
            
            let gitHubList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(GitHubAPIlist.self, from: data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.gitHubList = gitHubList
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I get 2 errors:

```
'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized
```

on the line with `URLSession` and

```
Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
```

on the line with the `}` after the `.resume()` command

Are there some obsolete syntaxes in the code or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this approach, to get you data from github. Works very well for me:

```
class NetworkingManager: ObservableObject{
    @Published var gitHubList: [Item] = []

    init() {
        loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=CoreData&per_page=20") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.gitHubList = response.items
                }
            } catch {
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
    
}

struct Root: Codable {
    let totalCount: Int
    let incompleteResults: Bool
    let items: [Item]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalCount = "total_count"
        case incompleteResults = "incomplete_results"
        case items
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable, Codable {
    let keysURL, statusesURL, issuesURL: String
    let id: Int
    let url: String
    let pullsURL: String
    // ... more properties

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case keysURL = "keys_url"
        case statusesURL = "statuses_url"
        case issuesURL = "issues_url"
        case id
        case url
        case pullsURL = "pulls_url"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var netManager = NetworkingManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(netManager.gitHubList) { item in
                Text(item.url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared the subject but didn't initialize it

```
var didChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkingManager, Never>()
```

---

However actually you don't need the subject, mark `gitHubList` as `@Published` (and delete the subject).
And if you are only interested in the `items` declare

```
@Published var gitHubList = [Repository]()
```

and assign

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.gitHubList = gitHubList.items
}
```

The `@Published` property wrapper will update the view.

---

In the view declare `NetworkingManager` as `@StateObject`

```
@StateObject private var networkManager = NetworkingManager()
```

and in the rendering area refer to

```
List(networkManager.gitHubList...
```

Notes:

- Forget the tutorial , the video is more than two years old which are ages in terms of Swift(UI)'s evolution speed.
- Ignoring errors and force unwrapping the result of the JSON decoder is very bad practice. Handle the potential URLSession error and catch and handle the potential decoding error.

Comment: Thank you for helping me yet again, @vadian :) 
Maybe I am catching this stuff to slow, but I did something like this:

'List(networkManager.gitHubList.fullName.identified(by: \.htmlUrl)) { repository in
            Text(repository.name)}'

And I get the error:

'Value of type '[Repository]' has no member 'fullName''


Also to get the results I need to use the convertFromSnakeCase key Decoding Strategy. Could you advise on how to use it in this case?

Comment: No, in `Repository` adopt `Identifiable` (right after `Decodable`). Then simply write `List(networkManager.gitHubList) { repository in `. And don't touch the key decoding strategy. By the way I recommend to rename `gitHubList` as `repositories`.

Comment: `[Repository]` is actually a set we transformed JSON items to in another thread (when I was level lower with all this http Xcode stuff):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70612447/no-value-associated-with-key-codingkeys-while-trying-to-get-data-from-github-api

When I tried to add `:Identifiable` there, I got 3 errors:

`Type 'GitHubAPIlist' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

`Protocol 'Identifiable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

`Type 'Repository' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`,

@vadian

Comment: I mean `struct Repository: Decodable, Identifiable {...`. And `GitHubAPIlist` is also a confusing name because it's **not** a list.

Comment: Right, @vadian, changed the name back to `Root` (in the code above too). Tried to follow the tutorial which was much easier thanks to your previous help (they gave it the custom name).

When I add Identifiable in the `Repository` struct, I get the comment that I need to add the `"control stubs"`. When I click `Fix`, Repository stops conforming to Decodable. I also tried setting `htmlUrl` as control stub, but then it stopped being identified as a String...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what keys you are going to decode. Maybe start with the few keys in your previous question and add more keys later. The conformance to `Decodable` is mandatory. Or look for a contemporary tutorial like those on hackingwithswift.com I highly recommend to go through 100 Days of SwiftUI on this site.

Comment: Thanks, I will.